# Is it possible to change font sizes in forecast::autoplot()?

Tags: r, time-series, visualization, forecast

In order to make a time series app with plot for analysis, I want to use the autoplot function of the forecast package, to provide stl decomposition.

However, it seems like there is no functionality given, to resize the text size of x and y axis. The base plot() arguments have no effect:

```
library(forecast)

co2 %>% 
decompose() %>% 
autoplot(
         cex.lab = 11,
         cex.axis = 11,
         cex.main = 13,
         cex.sub = 13)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`autoplot` comes from ggplot2. So you will need to use the ggplot2 functions to adjust items from the `autoplot`.

E.g. for adjusting the title size:

```
co2 %>% 
  decompose() %>% 
  autoplot() +
  theme(title = element_text(size = 13)
        )
```